# How to detach Windows 8 account from my Hotmail.com account?

Tags: windows-8

My Windows 8 username/password is attached to my Hotmail.com account. I am not how this happened. I think the installation asked me for it however I don't like this arrangement. 
I need to use a separate account which is not attached to anything external.

How do I remove this account from Windows? Is it checking my Hotmail password every time I log into the computer? This account is an admin account.

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: The user name and password for the computer IS my hotmail account and password.

Answer (score 9):

Open the side bar. With a touch-screen or tablet, swipe from the right, otherwise hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Go to Settings and click Change PC Settings. Under Users you can unlink the Hotmail account.

To answer your second question, it is checking your credentials against your Hotmail account. Since the account is linked to your Windows 8 user account, it can automatically  log you in to mail, chat, etc using the credentials you supply when you log in.

Comment: Thanks @Serneum, this answer should be marked as correct answer!