# Windows 8.1 2 in 1 Tablet tied to unused Hotmail account whose password is forgotten?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, passwords, hotmail

**Windows 8.1 2 in 1 Tablet tied to unused Hotmail account whose password is forgotten?**

I have some old family folks who did not realize they created this, then they lent the machine to another old family member and now nobody remembers this password and this Outlook/ Hotmail account was never used by them.

Apparently it was created by them when they went through the OOBE fresh machine process scenario.

I am doing some major tech house cleaning for them.

I doubt if we can do a reset via MS/ Hotmail and get a new password as we do not really have access to the Hotmail account as it was never used by anyone.

Any other ideas on bypassing this, using some Boot CD to get through this?

PS: We can't use this as Microsoft has baked in - integrated the Hotmail account into the local account, there seems to be NO separate original local account. That is bad.
[How to detach Windows 8 account from my Hotmail.com account?](https://superuser.com/questions/528349/how-to-detach-windows-8-account-from-my-hotmail-com-account)